# How would I store input values corresponding to a date in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm trying to build a timesheet tracking app with Vue JS where people can log how many hours per day they have worked (not on a specific task but rather in total how many hours they simply worked that day). I have put my code in a fiddle just to demonstrate what I wish the app to look like: https://jsfiddle.net/L5u1fc0a/5/

How can I make sure that the value the user puts in (say '8' in the input field corresponding to July 1) and then hit `››` (which will change the view to display the next period) is not transferred over and shown as '8' under July 16?

Basically, I wish to make sure that the number the user puts in relates to the **current** month they are viewing.

Comment: Currently you are displaying just raw month day and week day as your column names, which are completely unrelated to the row with inputs, so your `<<` and `>>` only change table's headers. You need to map week day and month to your rows. Each half of month should have their own row of values.

Comment: Yes, I figured it would be something along those lines - any idea on how I can map the dates to the inputs?